# Elegant way to get a value that may or may not be an observable

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that sometimes returns a value wrapped in an observable and other times returns a plain value. Is there an elegant way to get at the value? Currently I am using this strategy:

```
let mayBeAnObservable = getData();
let resultObservable = mayBeAnObservable instanceof Observable ? mayBeAnObservable : Observable.of(mayBeAnObservable)
resultObservable.subscribe(resultValue => dostuff(resultValue));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you did is okay. If you really want a more elegant solution, let your `getData()` always return an Observable. Even if whatever that makes it not an observable, just wrap it with `Observable.of()`, like what you already did:

```
const getData = ()=>{

    let someData = someOperations();

    if(normalCondition){
        return someData;
    }

    if(forWhateverReasonItsNotObservable){
        return Observable.of(someData)
    }
}
```

Choose a side. A safer side. If there is a chance your service may return an observable, it's better to always return an `Observable`. Reason? You gain all the benefits of reactive programming - You can `.map()`, you can `.filter()`, you can `.delay()`, you can `.buffer()` - you can do all sorts of operations to the `observables`; which may not be that handy if you are just handling it as a primitive value.

Comment: The "getData" function is my stand in for interfaces defined by Angular. I am working on testing some of our custom implementations and didn't want to change the code I am testing if possible. But I agree with you in principle that you should pick a side and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following function(with support for Promises and plain data):

```js
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { isPromise } from 'rxjs/util/isPromise';
import { isFunction } from 'rxjs/util/isFunction';

const isObservable = v => isFunction(v.subscribe);

export default function(data) {
  if (isObservable(data)) return data;
  if (isPromise(data)) return fromPromise(data);
  return of(data);
}
```

I'm not the author of it, and here is the original source and tests for it - https://github.com/zxbodya/router1-app-template/tree/master/src/utils